Algebraic Proof of Equivalence
I am struggling to show that these two expressions are equivalent. They appear to have perfect graphical overlap on Desmos, but I want to be able to show it algebraically.
$$\frac{1}{4x}\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(1+2x\right)^{2}}\right)+\frac{2}{x^{2}}$$
and
$$\frac{\left(1+x\right)}{x^{2}}\left(\frac{2\left(1+x\right)}{\ 1+2x}\right)-\frac{\left(1+3x\right)}{\left(1+2x\right)^{2}}$$
I have been working on this for a while and I end up with terms I am unable to cancel. Not sure if this means the expressions are approximately equal within a certain domain and then eventually are unequal. Here is as far as I have gotten:
$$\frac{1}{4x}-\frac{1}{1+4x+4x^{2}}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}=\frac{\left(1+x\right)}{x^{2}}\frac{\left(2+2x\right)}{\left(1+2x\right)}-\ \frac{1+3x}{1+4x+4x^{2}}$$
$$\frac{1}{4x}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}-\frac{1}{1+4x+4x^{2}}=\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(\frac{2}{1+2x}+\frac{2x}{1+2x\ }\right)-\frac{1}{1+4x+4x^{2}}-\frac{3x}{1+4x+4x^{2}}$$
$$\frac{1}{4x}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}=\frac{2}{x^{2}+2x^{3}}+\frac{4}{x+2x^{2}}+\frac{2}{1+2x}-\frac{3x}{1+4x+4x^{2}}$$
I am used to simplifying expressions, but here is where I began to give common denominators to hopefully show equivalence.
$$\frac{x+8}{4x^{2}}+\frac{3x}{1+4x+4x^{2}}=\ \frac{2+4x+2x^{2}}{x^{2}+2x^{3}}$$
$$\frac{8+33x+36x^{2}+16x^{3}}{4x^{2}+16x^{3}+16x^{4}}=\frac{2+4x+2x^{2}}{x^{2}+2x^{3}}$$
Cross-multiplying:
$$8x^{2}+33x^{3}+36x^{4}+16x^{5}+16x^{3}+66x^{4}+72x^{5}+32x^{6}=8x^{2}+32x^{3}+32x^{4}+16x^{3}+64x^{4}+64x^{5}+8x^{4}+32x^{5}+32x^{6}$$
Simplifying and cancelling terms:
$$33x^{3}+102x^{4}+88x^{5}=32x^{3}+104x^{4}+96x^{5}$$
These sides are of course unequal. But I am not sure where I went wrong with this, or if it is again just an approximate equality since the sides are similar.
Adding on, I am unsure if this general approach is the right one to take. Are there other ways to go about showing equivalence aside from this?

Add more details about the terms that you cannot cancel. Otherwise, this question is missing context and goes against MathSE policies and will be downvoted and closed soon.

By checking with WA you can see that the two are actually identical, so you must have made a small mistake. Instead of cross-multiplying do a classical common denominator
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{4x}\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(1+2x\right)^{2}}\right)+\frac{2}{x^{2}}&=\frac{(1+2x)^2-1}{4x\left(1+2x\right)^{2}}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}\\
&=\frac{4x^2+4x}{4x\left(1+2x\right)^{2}}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}\\
&=\frac{x+1}{\left(1+2x\right)^{2}}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}\\
&=\frac{(x+1)x^2+2(1+2x)^2}{x^{2}(1+2x)^2}\\
&=\frac{x^3+9x^2+8x+2}{x^{2}(1+2x)^2}
\end{align*}
a similar approach for the second expression will lead you to the same result.
EDIT: and in your calculations, there is unfortunately a mistake already at the very beginning:
$$\frac{1}{4x}\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(1+2x\right)^{2}}\right)+\frac{2}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{4x}-\frac{1}{\color{red}{4x}\cdot(1+4x+4x^{2})}+\frac{2}{x^{2}}$$
and in general expanding an expression (in the denominator) when it's already a product is advised against, as it cannot simplify.

Thanks for your help. I confirmed with a classical common denominator that the second expression leads to the same result. As a follow-up question: if I were to algebraically get from that first expression to the second expression, then would it make sense to go through this equivalent form, or is there a more direct route?

I don't see a faster way to be honest: the two forms are so non-standard that it's more of an algebraic game than a logic bond between them.
